# Ender 3 S1 Pro error "extrude below min temp"

Tags: creality, ender3

When I start my print it goes to home the z-axis and then I get the error "extrude below min temp" error (I have an Ender 3 S1 Pro)

Comment: We will probably need (a lot) more details in order to be able to provide a solution - take a look at other highly voted questions to see what is required.

Comment: There are details missing here, but it is possible that the OP is new enough to 3D printing that they don't know what is helpful.

Comment: Hi and welcome to 3DPrinting.SE! Indeed, it is hard to answer this question without a little more context. Know that printers are usually protected against extrusion at low temperatures (usually 170 °C), so you are either extruding at a too low temperature or there is something broken in the electric circuit. Please troubleshoot a little and put that in the question!

Answer (score 0):

Please excuse this answer if it is too simplistic or pedantic.  I don't know how much experience you have, and getting started can be very confusing.

The error message is because, for some reason, the hot end is not being measured as hot enough to soften the plastic enough for the extruder to push it through the nozzle.  Why can this be?

If your printer has a nozzle temperature display, check that it is in the right ballpark, 180 °C or higher.  My printer shows both the commanded and measured temperatures.  I am unfamiliar with your printer.  If the commanded temperature is 0 °C, the G-code may be wrong, ie., it may not have a temperature setting command, or the sensor could be broken.  If the commanded temperature is not displayed, or the actual temperature displays as roughly ambient temperature, the temperature command could be missing, or there could be a problem with the heating system.  If the actual temperature displays as significantly (more than 10 °C) different from ambient, I would look to the sensor for the problem.

Moving to the nozzle, check to see if it is hot when the error is displayed.  At full temperature, you should be able to melt a piece of filament by pressing it against the nozzle.

I could explore the failure tree further, but if you check these things the answer may be clear.  If not, please add your observations to this question.